# Selenium select_by_value and then print the option text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm scraping some data from the WTO and I need to select the importer from a dropdown menu. For importer 137 (Vietnam), my code finds the menu, selects index 137 and shows the data. However, I also want my code to print the label or the country corresponding to index 137 (Vietnam) but I'm struggling with such task.

This is basically what I have to select importer 137:

```
importer=137
time.sleep(1)
mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_c_cboImporter"))
mySelect.select_by_index(importer)
```

And here is the html of the menu:

```
<select name="ctl00$c$cboExporter" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$c$cboExporter\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_c_cboExporter" class="ListControl" style="width:100%;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;font-family:Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#333399;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;border-color:#6291CC;background-color:White;">
<option value="A000">Select an Exporter</option>
<option selected="selected" value="C004">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="C008">Albania</option>
<option value="C012">Algeria</option>
<option value="C020">Andorra</option>
<option value="C024">Angola</option>
<option value="C028">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="C032">Argentina</option>
<option value="C051">Armenia</option>
<option value="C036">Australia</option>
<option value="C031">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="C044">Bahamas</option>
<option value="C048">Bahrain, Kingdom of</option>
<option value="C050">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="C052">Barbados</option>
<option value="C112">Belarus</option>
<option value="C084">Belize</option>
<option value="C204">Benin</option>
<option value="C064">Bhutan</option>
<option value="C068">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
<option value="C070">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option value="C072">Botswana</option>
<option value="C076">Brazil</option>
<option value="C096">Brunei Darussalam</option>
<option value="C854">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="C108">Burundi</option>
<option value="C132">Cabo Verde</option>
<option value="C116">Cambodia</option>
<option value="C120">Cameroon</option>
<option value="C124">Canada</option>
<option value="C140">Central African Republic</option>
<option value="C148">Chad</option>
<option value="C152">Chile</option>
<option value="C156">China</option>
<option value="C170">Colombia</option>
<option value="C174">Comoros</option>
<option value="C178">Congo</option>
<option value="C188">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="C384">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
<option value="C192">Cuba</option>
<option value="C180">Democratic Republic of the Congo</option>
<option value="C262">Djibouti</option>
<option value="C212">Dominica</option>
<option value="C214">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="C218">Ecuador</option>
<option value="C818">Egypt</option>
<option value="C222">El Salvador</option>
<option value="C226">Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="C748">Eswatini</option>
<option value="C231">Ethiopia</option>
<option value="U918">European Union</option>
<option value="C242">Fiji</option>
<option value="C266">Gabon</option>
<option value="C270">The Gambia</option>
<option value="C268">Georgia</option>
<option value="C288">Ghana</option>
<option value="C308">Grenada</option>
<option value="C320">Guatemala</option>
<option value="C324">Guinea</option>
<option value="C624">Guinea-Bissau</option>
<option value="C328">Guyana</option>
<option value="C332">Haiti</option>
<option value="C340">Honduras</option>
<option value="C344">Hong Kong, China</option>
<option value="C352">Iceland</option>
<option value="C356">India</option>
<option value="C360">Indonesia</option>
<option value="C364">Iran</option>
<option value="C368">Iraq</option>
<option value="C376">Israel</option>
<option value="C388">Jamaica</option>
<option value="C392">Japan</option>
<option value="C400">Jordan</option>
<option value="C398">Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="C404">Kenya</option>
<option value="C410">Korea, Republic of</option>
<option value="C414">Kuwait, the State of</option>
<option value="C417">Kyrgyz Republic</option>
<option value="C418">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
<option value="C422">Lebanese Republic</option>
<option value="C426">Lesotho</option>
<option value="C430">Liberia</option>
<option value="C434">Libya</option>
<option value="C438">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="C446">Macao, China</option>
<option value="C450">Madagascar</option>
<option value="C454">Malawi</option>
<option value="C458">Malaysia</option>
<option value="C462">Maldives</option>
<option value="C466">Mali</option>
<option value="C478">Mauritania</option>
<option value="C480">Mauritius</option>
<option value="C484">Mexico</option>
<option value="C498">Moldova, Republic of</option>
<option value="C496">Mongolia</option>
<option value="C893">Montenegro</option>
<option value="C504">Morocco</option>
<option value="C508">Mozambique</option>
<option value="C104">Myanmar</option>
<option value="C516">Namibia</option>
<option value="C524">Nepal</option>
<option value="C554">New Zealand</option>
<option value="C558">Nicaragua</option>
<option value="C562">Niger</option>
<option value="C566">Nigeria</option>
<option value="C807">North Macedonia</option>
<option value="C578">Norway</option>
<option value="C512">Oman</option>
<option value="C586">Pakistan</option>
<option value="C591">Panama</option>
<option value="C598">Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="C600">Paraguay</option>
<option value="C604">Peru</option>
<option value="C608">Philippines</option>
<option value="C634">Qatar</option>
<option value="C643">Russian Federation</option>
<option value="C646">Rwanda</option>
<option value="C659">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
<option value="C662">Saint Lucia</option>
<option value="C670">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
<option value="C882">Samoa</option>
<option value="C678">Sao Tomé and Principe</option>
<option value="C682">Saudi Arabia, Kingdom of</option>
<option value="C686">Senegal</option>
<option value="C892">Serbia</option>
<option value="C690">Seychelles</option>
<option value="C694">Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="C702">Singapore</option>
<option value="C090">Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="C706">Somalia</option>
<option value="C710">South Africa</option>
<option value="C728">South Sudan</option>
<option value="C144">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="C736">Sudan</option>
<option value="C740">Suriname</option>
<option value="C756">Switzerland</option>
<option value="C760">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
<option value="C158">Chinese Taipei</option>
<option value="C762">Tajikistan</option>
<option value="C834">Tanzania</option>
<option value="C764">Thailand</option>
<option value="C626">Timor-Leste</option>
<option value="C768">Togo</option>
<option value="C776">Tonga</option>
<option value="C780">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
<option value="C788">Tunisia</option>
<option value="C792">Turkey</option>
<option value="C800">Uganda</option>
<option value="C804">Ukraine</option>
<option value="C784">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="C840">United States of America</option>
<option value="C858">Uruguay</option>
<option value="C860">Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="C548">Vanuatu</option>
<option value="C862">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
<option value="C704">Viet Nam</option>
<option value="C887">Yemen</option>
<option value="C894">Zambia</option>
<option value="C716">Zimbabwe</option>
```

After selecting the importer 137, I want my code to find the country corresponding to importer 137, based on the options in the selected dropdown menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `first_selected_option` to return currently selected

```
selected = mySelect.first_selected_option
print(selected.text)
```

Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

url = 'http://www.debentures.com.br/exploreosnd/consultaadados/sndemumclique/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
options = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="ctl00$ddlEmi"] option')))

importer = 3

mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="ctl00$ddlEmi"]'))
mySelect.select_by_index(importer)
selected = mySelect.first_selected_option
print(selected.text)
```

---

You can use an attribute = value css selector to get the option element then grab the .text from it

```
label = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="C704"]').text
```

---

But you could avoid index and select by text

```
select.select_by_visible_text('Viet Nam')
```

---

Or grab all the options

```
options = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[name="ctl00$c$cboExporter"] option')
```

and then index into that and use .text to return the associated value

Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'http://www.debentures.com.br/exploreosnd/consultaadados/sndemumclique/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
options = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="ctl00$ddlEmi"] option')))
options[5].click()
print(options[5].text)
```

---

If you want to try a loop over all then maybe something like

```
options = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[name="ctl00$c$cboExporter"] option')

for option in options:
    option.click()
    print(option.text)
```

Here is an example loop

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'http://www.debentures.com.br/exploreosnd/consultaadados/sndemumclique/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
options = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="ctl00$ddlEmi"] option')))

for option in options[1:]:
    option.click()
    print(option.text)
```

Comment: Thanks!! The problem is that I want to use the index because I'm looping over each country. Basically what I want is to select index 137 and then to print the country corresponding with such index value. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you loop over all options by grabbing collection of webElements using my last example then you can select as you go along and use .text on current webElement to get the name

Answer (score 0):

Just before you click the option, you can locate it and get its text:

```
mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_c_cboImporter"))
# with css
text = mySelect.find_element_by_css("option:nth-of-type({})".format(importer)).text
# xpath
text = mySelect.find_element_by_xpath("option[{}])".format(importer)).text
mySelect.select_by_index(importer)
```